# Finding two equal columns in two different table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find values in one table, where two columns are equal in another table, I tried creating a new column in these tables with both values `( "column 1" - "column 2" )` it does work but takes ALOT of time, is there a better way ?

tables are like this

```
TABLE ONE
NAME | ADDRESS | ZIPCODE | NUMBER | ZIPNUMBER | CITY

TABLE TWO
DATE | ZIPCODE | NUMBER | ZIPNUMBER
```

Then I use

```
Select * 
from t1 a 
inner join t2 b on a.zipnumber = b.zipnumber
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes defined in both tables? You said you want to match 2 columns in a 2nd table but you're only matching 1 column in the 2nd table, which columns were you looking to match.

Comment: I want to match ZIPCODE and NUMBER, the way I found to do this was to create a new column called zipnumber with both columns using concat  `concat(zipcode, ' - ' , number)`

Comment: And why don't you join it on both columns respectively? `on a.zipcode = b.zipcode AND a.number = b.number` **also you haven't said whether or not you have indexes in your table.**

Comment: @Prix I did had indexes but I created on index for each column not one index for both, so I was using index wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start, add two-column index on your both tables:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD INDEX (zipcode, number);
ALTER TABLE t2 ADD INDEX (zipcode, number);
```

Then you can execute:

```
SELECT * FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.zipcode=t2.zipcode AND t1.number=t2.number
```

It will be fast because it will use indexes

Comment: it went from hours to just 69 seconds... Thank you... really simple query that solves all.